# how to avoid crawler to follow anchor empty link (with jquery action)

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I have in my site some links that are just used to display informative popups.

For example I have something like :

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">show more info</a>
```

And in my .js file I have something like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myLink).click(function() {
      displayPopup();
});
});
```

But google crawler or other crawler follow the link and tell me that it's a wrong link (it goes to my /usercontrol folder...)

How can I avoid crawler to follow this link ?

Should I put :

```
<a href="#" id="myLink" onclick="return false">show more info</a>
```

and keep my jquery as it is ?

Or put return false in Jquery click event ?

Or not use an anchor but a div instead ? is it gonna work in all browser in this case ?

Thanks for all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<a href="#" id="myLink" rel="nofollow">show more info</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's not really a link, you can use a span tag instead, and style it to look like you want. It will work in any browser that has Javascript enabled, just as your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @Darin suggested, using the `rel` attribute with a value of [`nofollow`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow) is a good technique.

However, to prevent search engines from accessing or indexing parts of your site, you should use the [Robots exclusion standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard). See the [interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow#Interpretation_by_the_individual_search_engines) of nofollow by various search engines.

To tell all user agents to not follow or index a given url, use a robots.txt file with the following contents:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /usercontrol/
```

Google and all other bots should respect the contents of your robots.txt file, and not index any links starting with the path `/usercontrol/`.